# About is downgraded or replacing SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

SQLServer2008 is on a PC.  When we upgraded to SQLServer2008, an ODBC error started to appear:

```
State: 37000,Native: 155,Origin: [Microsoft][Sql Natize Client][SQL Server]
'TRUNCATE_ONLY' is not recognized as a BACKUP option.
```

Now this is error message has started to become a common occurrence. I am troubled.

How to downgrade it?
Please help me

Answer (score 2):

The error is not a serious one.  It's from your transaction log backup routine.  (probably a SQL Agent job).  You're trying to run "backup log [databasename] with truncate only" or something like that.

That's the old way of doing it.  You can turn that script off, and set the database to "Simple" recovery mode, so your transaction logs don't grow out of hand.

Or set up a real transaction log backup.

But either way, stop trying to truncate the transaction log and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you for commented.
Do you know contents to become that it does not serious

Answer (score 2):

To add to what Bob says above, here's a long article I wrote on my blog about managing the size of your transaction log correctly: [Importance of proper transaction log size management](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Importance-of-proper-transaction-log-size-management.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The TRUNCATE_ONLY option for the log backup has been deprecated in MS SQL 2008. 
 - One solution is to switch the database in simple recovery mode and then back to full recovery mode.

ALTER DATABASE *database_name* SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
go

CHECKPOINT
go

ALTER DATABASE *database_name* SET RECOVERY FULL
go

- Another option would be to checkpoint the databse and backup the log without the TRUNCATE_ONLY option (with a checkpoint and a log backup the log should shrink just enough)

CHECKPOINT
go

BACKUP LOG *database_name* to disk = '' 
go